# Manage CD/DVD access on small Windows network

Tags: windows-7, dvd

I have a small Server2008/Win7 network and I want to restrict CD/DVD access for all but one of my users. I set the below GPO, but is there a way I can I give one specific user access to the CD/DVD drive on all workstations without giving this person admin rights?

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Removable Storage Access
CD and DVD: Deny execute access
CD and DVD: Deny read access
CD and DVD: Deny write access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same policy, except use the one under the "User Configuration" branch instead of the "Computer Configuration" branch. That way it's applied to User objects in AD instead of Computer objects.

One way to apply it:

- Create two new GPOs, one that sets the drive access to Deny, and one that Allows it.
- Move the User into their own (sub) OU.
- Apply the Deny GPO you just made to the (parent) OU that contains all the *Users* who shouldn't have access.
- Apply the Allow GPO to the (sub) OU that contains the User(s) you want to allow drive access to.